# how to use module from another python VM

Tags: python

I have two python VM instance running, each of them have some modules

```
/Path/to/Dir1
  -main
  -moduleA
/Path/to/Dir2
  -main
  -moduleB
```

How could I import moduleB into moduleA? I added moduleB into PYTHONPATH, but don't see moduleB from moduleA PYTHONPATH

Is there any way that we can import modules across interpreters?

Comment: If they're in separate VMs, how could you "add into PYTHONPATH"?

Comment: Are you trying to use this as an inter-process communication mechanism? If you are, first, this is a terrible way to do inter-process communication, and second, it probably won't behave anything like you expect, especially with regard to processes seeing each others' changes.

Comment: If you're not trying to use this for inter-process communication, then the fact that you have two Python interpreters active doesn't seem relevant. Each one handles its own imports.

Comment: I mean I tried to put moduleB into its own PYTHONPATH, but unfortunately, it cannot be used by ModuleA, I need use moduleB in ModuleA @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: @user2357112, you are correct, is there anyway that I can import across interpreters?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have two existing code base, each of them has their own interpreters. Both of them run in the same system. But partial code in baseA, can be reused by baseB. If I can reference baseA, I don't need add duplicate code in baseB